# Image is duplicated using setShadowLayer() in Android

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, paint, shadow

I'm using the method "`setShadowLayer`" of the class "`Paint`" on Android to apply a shadow effect on a Bitmap image. However, instead of creating the shadow effect, the image is duplicated.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase radius of it and it will give shadow effect:

```
mPaint.setShadowLayer(5, getWidth(), getHeight()-2, Color.BLUE);
```

here 5 is my radius.